# Why I can't handle multipart upload in this Spring Boot application? I obtain "no matching editors or conversion strategy found"

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am working on a **Spring Boot** application and I am finding some difficulties trying to implement a controller method that handle the **multipart file upload**.

To do it I have adapted this **Spring MVC** tutorial: http://www.codejava.net/coding/upload-files-to-database-with-spring-mvc-and-hibernate

Basically to add the multipart support to my Spring Boot project I have not added this bean in a configuration class (as done in the tutorial):

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver getCommonsMultipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(20971520);   // 20MB
    multipartResolver.setMaxInMemorySize(1048576);  // 1MB
    return multipartResolver;
}
```

but I have just add this properties into the **application.properties** file of my application:

```
multipart.enabled=true      // enable file uploading
```

So it should be enabled.

Then I have this controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/AccomodationMedia")
public class AccomodationMediaController {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AccomodationMediaController.class);

    @Autowired
    private AccomodationMediaService accomodationMediaService;


    public AccomodationMediaController() {
        log.debug("AccomodationMediaController init");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/doUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String handleFileUpload(HttpServletRequest request,
                                   @RequestParam CommonsMultipartFile[] fileUpload) throws Exception {

        if (fileUpload != null && fileUpload.length > 0) {
            for (CommonsMultipartFile currentFile : fileUpload){

                System.out.println("Saving file: " + currentFile.getOriginalFilename());

                accomodationMediaService.saveAccomodationMedia(currentFile);

            }
        }

        return "Success";
    }

}
```

As you can see in the previous code it contains the **handleFileUpload()** method that handle **Http POST Request** toward the URL: **AccomodationMedia/doUpload** URL.

Then I have created this standalone standard HTML page to test the behavior of this **handleFileUpload()** controller method:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Spring MVC - Hibernate File Upload to Database Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div align="center">
        <h1>Spring MVC - Hibernate File Upload to Database Demo</h1>
        <form method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/AccomodationMedia/doUpload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>Pick file #1:</td>
                    <td><input type="file" name="fileUpload" size="50" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Pick file #2:</td>
                    <td><input type="file" name="fileUpload" size="50" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" value="Upload" /></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This page contains the form to insert 2 files to upload. 
As you can see the form submission generate a POST request toward **http://localhost:8080/AccomodationMedia/doUpload**

So I start my application in debug mode putting a brackpoint at the beginning of the select a file and I click the previousn **handleFileUpload()** controller method. Then I select a file in the previous page and I click on the **Upload** button that generate the POST request.

The problem is that it not enter in the **handleFileUpload()** execution but I am obtaining the following error message into my stacktrace:

```
[DEBUG] 2017-01-02 16:35:14 [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:865)] [http-nio-8080-exec-10] DispatcherServlet - DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing POST request for [/AccomodationMedia/doUpload]
[DEBUG] 2017-01-02 16:35:14 [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:310)] [http-nio-8080-exec-10] RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Looking up handler method for path /AccomodationMedia/doUpload
[DEBUG] 2017-01-02 16:35:14 [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:317)] [http-nio-8080-exec-10] RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Returning handler method [public java.lang.String com.betrivius.controller.media.AccomodationMediaController.handleFileUpload(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile[]) throws java.lang.Exception]
[DEBUG] 2017-01-02 16:35:14 [org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:167)] [http-nio-8080-exec-10] ServletInvocableHandlerMethod - Error resolving argument [1] [type=[Lorg.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile;]
HandlerMethod details: 
Controller [com.betrivius.controller.media.AccomodationMediaController]
Method [public java.lang.String com.betrivius.controller.media.AccomodationMediaController.handleFileUpload(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile[]) throws java.lang.Exception]

org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type [java.util.LinkedList] to required type [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile[]]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile] to required type [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:119) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_65]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile] to required type [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:143) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertToTypedArray(TypeConverterDelegate.java:479) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:216) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:108) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:64) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:47) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.convertIfNecessary(DataBinder.java:688) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:115) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 51 more
[DEBUG] 2017-01-02 16:35:14 [org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:133)] [http-nio-8080-exec-10] ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Resolving exception from handler [public java.lang.String com.betrivius.controller.media.AccomodationMediaController.handleFileUpload(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile[]) throws java.lang.Exception]: org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type [java.util.LinkedList] to required type [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile[]]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile] to required type [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
[DEBUG] 2017-01-02 16:35:14 [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:370)] [http-nio-8080-exec-10] ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - Invoking @ExceptionHandler method: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String> com.betrivius.controller.exceptionHandler.ControllerExceptionHandler.handleException(org.apache.catalina.servlet4preview.http.HttpServletRequest,java.lang.Exception)
[ERROR] 2017-01-02 16:35:14 [com.betrivius.controller.exceptionHandler.ControllerExceptionHandler.handleException(ControllerExceptionHandler.java:106)] [http-nio-8080-exec-10] ControllerExceptionHandler - Request: http://localhost:8080/AccomodationMedia/doUpload  throws: 
org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert value of type [java.util.LinkedList] to required type [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile[]]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile] to required type [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:119) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:161) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:89) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.5.jar:8.5.5]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_65]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile] to required type [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:143) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertToTypedArray(TypeConverterDelegate.java:479) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:216) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:108) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.doConvert(TypeConverterSupport.java:64) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:47) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.convertIfNecessary(DataBinder.java:688) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver.java:115) ~[spring-web-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 51 more
[DEBUG] 2017-01-02 16:35:14 [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:250)] [http-nio-8080-exec-10] HttpEntityMethodProcessor - Written [Errore interno] as "text/html" using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@26feccf7]
[DEBUG] 2017-01-02 16:35:14 [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1044)] [http-nio-8080-exec-10] DispatcherServlet - Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
[DEBUG] 2017-01-02 16:35:14 [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1000)] [http-nio-8080-exec-10] DispatcherServlet - Successfully completed request
```

So the main cause of the error seems to be:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile] to required type [org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile]: no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

What exactly means? It seems that can't convert the uploaded file in the **CommonsMultipartFile[]** or something like this.

The only difference with the tutorial example are:

1) I am using **Spring Boot** and so I am activating multipart adding the property **multipart.enabled=true**.

2) Differently from the tutorial I am not using the **1.3.1** version of the **commons-fileupload** dependency but I am using the newer **1.3.2** version (but I don't think that it could be a problem)

What exactly means this error? How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that property adds in a commons multipart resolver?  I find that very suspicious.  Did you try adding in the resolver explicitly?  It may only enable the multipart resolution in the dispatcher servlet, which will auto detect a multipart resolver if one is available in the application context.

Comment: Program to interfaces `MultipartFile` not the concrete class `CommonsMultipartFile`. (The latter is the one expecting the use of `commons-fileupload` but Spring Boot doesn't use `commons-fileupload` it uses the default file upload functionality from the Servlet Spec).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add the following code in **properties** file:

```
# multipart 
multipart.enabled=true
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=500000KB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=500000KB
```

and replace the @RequestParam CommonsMultiPartFile by `@RequestParam MultipartFile pic`

```
@PostMapping("/up")
public String saveFile(@RequestParam MultipartFile pic,@RequestParam String author) {
    System.out.println("osgn jsm ojmpdn");
    System.out.println(pic);
    System.out.println(author);
    return "ok";
}
```

Comment: Works perfect in spring boot 1.5.18